# Graph API: BadGateway when trying to create a Team

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm using Graph API `v1.0` with application permissions. I'm able to create a Group, after creating the Group I try to create a Team. The API call always fails with:

```
{
   "error": {
     "innerError": {
       "date": "2020-02-22T00:58:53", 
       "request-id": "ca92dfa7-283f-49e4-af47-b46f6d8ad53f"
     }, 
     "message": "Failed to execute backend request.", 
     "code": "BadGateway"
   }
 }
```

The body of my request is:

```
{
  "memberSettings": {
    "allowCreateUpdateChannels": False,
  },
  "messagingSettings": {
    "allowUserEditMessages": True,
    "allowUserDeleteMessages": True,
  },
  "funSettings": {
    "allowGiphy": False,
     "giphyContentRating": "strict"
  },
  "discoverySettings": {
    "showInTeamsSearchAndSuggestions": False
  }
}
```

I've read the docs and retried up to 3 times with a 10 second delay. I've even inserted a 15 *minute* delay after creating the group to confirm that it is properly created and propagated. Neither of those changes has had any effect.

I've also tried using the new Beta API version of Create Team, and I get the same `BadGateway` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this relates anymore, but I have seen the same problem before and it was because the true and false values should not (according to JSON specs) not be capitalized first letter.

False -> false and True -> true

But this may be handled in serializers and deserializers now. But check it.

There is also an extra comma behind "allowCreateUpdateChannels" and "allowUserDeleteMessages" that necessarily doesn't need to be there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Graph API SDK 3.1.0. Try setting ODataType = null within the team objects

```
        var team = new GraphApi.Team
        {      
            MemberSettings = new GraphApi.TeamMemberSettings
            {
                AllowCreateUpdateChannels = true,
                ODataType = null
            },
            MessagingSettings = new GraphApi.TeamMessagingSettings
            {
                AllowUserEditMessages = true,
                AllowUserDeleteMessages = true,
                ODataType = null
            },
            FunSettings = new GraphApi.TeamFunSettings
            {
                AllowGiphy = true,
                GiphyContentRating = GraphApi.GiphyRatingType.Strict,
                ODataType = null
            },
            ODataType = null
        };
```